# allow only custom colors in color dialog

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i want to show a color dialog that only displays custom colors and no basic colors or any other color. How can I do this? Is it even possible?

[image: Color Dialog]

how can I hide the basic colors section in this dialog box and only show the custom colors section?

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to do something like that in the first place. Sounds like it'd just make the user's life more difficult. But alas, that's more of a question for [UX.SE](http://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: well...the reason is that I wanted the user to select a Color From the Color dialog and then I would  Fetch the Color name but I realized that Some OF the Colors in basic color Section are Unknown. or I Can't get their names through reflection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a pre-baked dialog, built into Windows.  Exact same one you see used in MSPaint's Edit Colors command for example.  These dialogs are exposed by Windows to help programmers provide a consistent UI to their users.  They'll learn to use it in one program and know how to use it in any other.  OpenFileDialog and PrintDialog are other examples.  No, you can't change it, that defeats the point.

Creating your own color dialog isn't terribly difficult.  You can get inspiration from this [magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164113.aspx)